# Updating a hashmap within a hashmap with a class

Tags: java

Sorry about the title really struggling to name this.  Lets see how the question goes.....

In java I have a class called book which contains the following code.  Where name is the book name, the hashMap string is the critics name and the hashMap Integer is the critic score.

```
public class book {

    private String name;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
```

I then have another class called bookRecord which contains the following code.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Book> bookRecord = new HashMap<Integer, Book>();
```

I have written a UI that allows me to enter a new book and save that book into the bookRecord.

The Integer in bookRecord is an ID for the book.
I have written a query to search by the ID and return the name of the book.  Now I want to be able to update the book if a new critic and score is available.

I have been playing with a for each loop to find the right key in the book record and then if the key is found another for each loop but I have confused myself.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

First option you make the `results` HashMap public and can achieve something like this:

```
Book uBook = records.get(BOOK_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE);
if (uBook != null) {
  uBook.results.put("New critic name", Critic_SCORE);
}
```

Seconds option is to leave the `results` private but add a new method `addCriticScore(String criticName, Integer score)`:

```
// In your class that updates the book
Book uBook = records.get(BOOK_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE);

// In the Book class
public void addCriticScore(String criticName, Integer score) {
  this.results.put(criticName, score);
}
```

P.S: Don't forget to rename your class `book` to `Book`. In `java` the class name is with capitals